# Multiple a record for failover

Tags: mongodb, dns, haproxy

I have **5** mongos server at amazon:

192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
192.168.1.4
192.168.1.5

and **2** HAProxy servers for load balancing:

192.168.1.6
192.168.1.7

- My domain is registered at: namecheap.com, let call it **domain.com**.

1)

can i point database.domain.com to both HAProxy servers?

if yes how?

2)

if HAProxy server: **192.168.1.6** fails will **192.168.1.7** take over?

3)

Can i control the timeout of the records?

Please explain to me how things work and how to make it work like i want.

I'm trying to understand how such system is setup for failover. I'm seeking

knowledge and not humiliation so either you try to help or dont do anything

please.

Answer (score 0):

Anna stay positive, we all are learning from each other. Well you need to create a replicaset of all of your mongodb servers. Replica set is a mongodb answer of handling failover.

Please see https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/replication/

To connect mongodb, you don't need any proxy servers. just point directly to mongodb primary. Depending on your application, mongodb connection string can look slightly different. Normally, it should be something like:

`mongodb://192.168.1.1,192.168.1.2,192.168.1.3,192.168.1.4,192.168.1.5/?replicaSet=<replicaset_name>`

See https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/

Comment: Hi Saleem, thanks for the kind support. Well i'm doing sharding like this: https://lukedemi.files.wordpress.com/2014/04/mongo-new-page.pngi'm doing that becouse i want to scale the write. What i'm having hard time of is that how to make my website pick the right mongos that is working

Comment: Well, sharding is a totally different beast and is not for redundancy and high availability. you need to setup config server/servers which will know which shard is where. Then you'll need to run one or more mongos  and point out config servers. Please see https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongos/ . your client need to point to any of mongos and no need to worry about of rest.

Comment: Again, if you are just looking for high availability, sharding is not what you want. You need to do sharding once your working set (data) is very large and can't fit in memory for best performance. see https://www.mongodb.com/presentations/sharding-best-practices-advanced-session and https://www.compose.io/articles/how-we-scale-mongodb/

Answer (score 0):

Just in further to @Saleem's answer, by way of explanation into DNS, multiple A records in DNS don't act as a failover, rather they act more like a load balancer in that your upstream DNS server will request the A record and will select one of the A records listed to return to you, and this record may change each time the time to live expires and your DNS server has to re-request the A record.

Some DNS servers are smart enough to request a new A record if the provided one doesn't work and so that gives you a certain level of psuedo-redundancy, but most do not have this feature enabled.

(source: [Using DNS for failover using multiple A records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319649/using-dns-for-failover-using-multiple-a-records))